# Correct Syntax Needed for Multi Dimension Adapter Pattern

Tags: java, adapter

I would like to enhance the adapter pattern to permit the retrieval of methods from a multi dimensional array. Unfortunately, my research on the proper syntax has not yielded a similar example. My final goal is to have a 3-dimensional array of methods. The example below has only 2-dimensions but I believe with your kind assistance I can extrapolate the correct syntax to additional dimensions.

```
package com.js;

public class Node {

    public void goNorth() { System.out.println("Driving North"); }
    public void goSouth() { System.out.println("Driving South"); }
    public void goEast()  { System.out.println("Driving East");  }
    public void goWest()  { System.out.println("Driving West");  }

    interface MoveAction {
        void move();
    }

    private MoveAction[][] moveActions = new MoveAction[][] {
      new MoveAction() { public void move() { goNorth(); } , { public void move() { goSouth(); },
      new MoveAction() { public void move() { goSouth(); } , { public void move() { goNorth(); },
      new MoveAction() { public void move() { goEast();  } , { public void move() { goWest();  },
      new MoveAction() { public void move() { goWest();  } , { public void move() { goEast();  },
    };

    public void move(int index) {
        moveActions[index][index].move();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int index = 0; index < 4;index++) {
            new Node().moveActions[index][index].move();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example pertains to the Java Programming Language.

Comment: The following identical error message is highlighted in Eclipse for
each line containing"  

new MoveAction() { public void move() {....

Error message:

Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ",", invalid ClassMemberDeclaration
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced contruct(s)